# state not changing on onChange event in react?

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```
function AddPost() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState({})
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(file);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField type='file' onChange={handleChange} label='image' variant='outlined' />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am not getting file info. on console, while i am selecting a file . Instead of that I am getting empty object why ?

Comment: What is `TextField`?

Comment: TextField is matetial-ui component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `useEffect` to besure you are doing your action after a state is updated. Here is an example :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(1);
    console.log('num =', num);
  }
  
  // Note the dependency array below
  React.useEffect(() => console.log('num (useEffect) = ', num), [num]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and here is [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-ymtbzf).

Here, on click, `num` will be `0` in the function, but it will be set to `1` in the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

The state update is performed asynchronously and only visible in the next render call.

In the next render call, `file` will be updated to the new value and then your (also new) function `handleChange` will use that value.

This means in your current code the log will always be off by one (empty object, file 1, file 2 etc.) when uploading one file after each other.

The behavior is described in the [documentation of the useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

To fix the log, simply write

```
const newFile = event.target.files[0];
setFile(newFile);
console.log(newFile);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just the file is not updated yet (whitin onChange) , so you see the initial state